# Jenkins setup wizard not loading

Tags: jenkins, installation, wizard

I am unable load jenkins setup wizard in centOS.

I am able to load initial page (Fig-1) where asking for initial password there I am entering initial password. But after clicking on the continue the page is not going to setup wizard. The page is keep on loading as shown in fig-2.

Fig-1:

[image]

fig-2

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just solved it by directly going to `<jenkins URL>/pluginManager/advanced` and entering my proxy information there.

Don't forget to restart it after that.

Answer (score 3):

Bouncing Jenkins worked for me

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well and I solved it by adding the following URL to my Pi-Hole Whitelist.

https://updates.jenkins.io

Comment: Agreed, I think this is why it hangs even though there is no error message, it seems to be trying to hit URLs for plugins or updates and cannot get through.

Comment: for everyone with a pi-hole setup: adding this URL to the whitelist is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved by stopping proxy on my host.
But I suggest you to see the details in "Your_jenkins_URL"/threadDump